# OpenStack Python Novaclient does not require authentication

Tags: python, openstack

I'm using OpenStack Diablo on RHEL6 with packages from GridDynamics.

Everything seems to work with the EC2 api, but when using python-novaclient, the system just allow access to any api commands regardless of the authentication provided.

See https://github.com/masom/Puck/blob/master/server/plugins/virtualization/nova.py#L42

I am not using Keystone for authentication (Waiting for essex to be released).

Why is nova blindly allowing anyone to issue api commands regardless of the authentication data provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `/etc/nova/api-paste.ini` had `noauth` and `ec2noauth`

Moving to the deprecated auth (not using keystone) by changing `noauth` to `auth` did it.